# Why does the documentation recommend that you reduce overdraw on Android devices?

Tags: android, ios, performance

Android developers are recommended to reduce overdraw in their apps.

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/overdraw.html

iOS developers are warned about overdraw, but it is not emphasized. Rather they have an option to color blended layers.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringGraphicsPerformance.html

From what I understand on iOS CoreGraphics puts layers into the GPU and the GPU combines them at render time. Calculating what pixels to show is easier when the pixels are not blended (alpha channel).

What is the technical difference that causes Android to focus on overdraw? Can you provide a technical reference?

Comment: It may help to read this old article: http://www.curious-creature.com/docs/android-performance-case-study-1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it's mainly due to the differences between the [Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm) and [Z-Buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering).

With the former, you draw every view from back to forth according to your layout, overdrawing pixels as necessary. This can lead to quite a bit of waste, since pixels need to be rendered regardless of whether they are occluded or not.

Z-Buffering can improve on this by using Z-Culling, where some pixels can be eliminated early if your layers are sorted properly.

Originally, Android used an entirely software based rendering stack, so Z-Buffering was not available and, as far as I know, a simple Painter's Algorithm was used. iOS was always based on hardware accelerated rendering and could thus take (some) advantage of Z-Buffering. But since Android 3.0, Android also started to implement Hardware based rendering.

Things aren't quite so simple in practice though. For one, using Hardware Layers and doing depth sorting incurs some cost as well, and if dealing with very simple drawing operations like mobile Apps do (like simply drawing a bitmap, opposed to complex pixel based lightning operations you have with 3D graphics), overdrawing pixels might actually be cheaper than trying to avoid it. When dealing with transparencies things obviously get a lot more complicated as well.

I assume that both Android and iOS use a combination of techniques, so Overdraw will most likely occur on both Platforms. It's a good idea in any scenario to try to avoid the problem entirely by trying to avoid unnecessary overlap.

Comment: "I assume that both Android and iOS use a combination of techniques, so Overdraw will most likely occur on both Platforms."

It would be nice to get a more concrete answer than this, but it may be difficult because the software/hardware implementation could change with newer versions.

Answer (score -1):

iOS developers are indeed instructed to avoid overdraw:

> Eliminate drawing when your app or its content is not visible; for example, when your app is in the background, or when its content is obscured by other views, clipped, or offscreen.

from the link you mentioned.

Comment: But the emphasis is still different. From what I understand CoreGraphics is very efficient at composing layers together once they have been defined, whereas Android documentation *seems* to be much more interested in pixel by pixel drawing efficiency. I was hoping to get more details on the under the hood differences that causes this.

Comment: It seems like apple is implementing their own "solution" to the problem, whereas in android they do nothing and let you control of how to overcome the problem.
Are you looking for some details regarding the CoreGraphics actions?